# Python - How to Choose Max In Groupby DataFrame Groups (While Allowing for Multiple Picks for Ties)

Tags: python, group-by

Apologies for the messy/unorganized post; it's my first post ever.

Background:
Within each state, and for every pollster (there are multiple polls per state), I want to pick the candidate with the highest percentage of the vote:

```
    import pandas as pd

    data = {'State': ['Texas','Texas','Texas','Texas',\
              'New York','New York',\
              'Pennsylvania','Pennsylvania','Pennsylvania',\
              'Pennsylvania','Pennsylvania','Pennsylvania'],
    'Pollster': ['Chuck Norris','Chuck Norris','Mike Jones','Mike Jones',\
                 'Sterling Cooper','Sterling Cooper',\
                 'Yinz','Yinz','Yinz','Wawa','Wawa','Wawa'],\
    'Party': ['Thems','RIPs','Thems','RIPs',\
              'Thems','RIPs',\
              'Thems','RIPs','LIBOR',\
              'Thems','RIPs','LIBOR'],\
    'Percentage of Vote' : [0.45, 0.55, 0.43, 0.57,\
                            .99,.01,\
                            .5,.5,0,\
                            1/3,1/3,1/3]}

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The problem is that, in Pennsylvania, there is a two-way tie in Yinz's poll, and a three-way tie in Wawa's poll. How can I pull out the candidate with the highest percentage in each group (poll within a given state), allowing for the possibility of pulling multiple candidates if there is a tie?
Here is the original data:

```
        State         Pollster        Party  Percentage of Vote
      0 Texas         Chuck Norris    Thems  0.450000
      1 Texas         Chuck Norris    RIPs   0.550000
      2 Texas         Mike Jones      Thems  0.430000
      3 Texas         Mike Jones      RIPs   0.570000
      4 New York      Sterling Cooper Thems  0.990000
      5 New York      Sterling Cooper RIPs   0.010000
      6 Pennsylvania  Yinz            Thems  0.500000
      7 Pennsylvania  Yinz            RIPs   0.500000
      8 Pennsylvania  Yinz            LIBOR  0.000000
      9 Pennsylvania  Wawa            Thems  0.333333
     10 Pennsylvania  Wawa            RIPs   0.333333
     11 Pennsylvania  Wawa            LIBOR  0.333333
```

Here is the desired output:

```
        State         Pollster        Party  Percentage of Vote
      1 Texas         Chuck Norris    RIPs   0.550000
      3 Texas         Mike Jones      RIPs   0.570000
      4 New York      Sterling Cooper Thems  0.990000
      6 Pennsylvania  Yinz            Thems  0.500000
      7 Pennsylvania  Yinz            RIPs   0.500000
      9 Pennsylvania  Wawa            Thems  0.333333
     10 Pennsylvania  Wawa            RIPs   0.333333
     11 Pennsylvania  Wawa            LIBOR  0.333333
```

Note how the top candidate in every poll remains, and multiple candidates are displayed for a poll only if there is a tie.

I've tried using:

```
    df.groupby(['State', 'Pollster'])
```

to group by polls within a state, but I'm lost as to what to do next.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You certainly have to do groupby & get the indexes of maximum value for "Percentage of Vote"... which will filter out desired result. Follow below code:

```
idx = df.groupby(['State','Pollster'])['Percentage of Vote'].transform(max) == df['Percentage of Vote']
df1 = df[idx]

# output of df1;

           State         Pollster  Party  Percentage of Vote
1          Texas     Chuck Norris   RIPs            0.550000
3          Texas       Mike Jones   RIPs            0.570000
4       New York  Sterling Cooper  Thems            0.990000
6   Pennsylvania             Yinz  Thems            0.500000
7   Pennsylvania             Yinz   RIPs            0.500000
9   Pennsylvania             Wawa  Thems            0.333333
10  Pennsylvania             Wawa   RIPs            0.333333
11  Pennsylvania             Wawa  LIBOR            0.333333
```